# Reading json files with utf-8 characters with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

I have a large json file with utf-8 encoded characters. How can I read this file and convert these characters to more readable version?
I have something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Wroc\u00c5\u0082aw"
}
```

and i want to have this:

```
{
    "name": "Wrocław"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON data contains [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) like this, you can convert it to proper Unicode by converting the string to Latin-1, then decoding the result as UTF-8.  This reverses whichever process produced the mojibake. (The fact that the strings come from JSON is inconsequential; this works for any mojibake strings of this type.)

```py
>>> s = "Wroc\u00c5\u0082aw"
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'Wrocław'
```

In the general case, you have to reverse-engineer what produced the mojibake, but this particular case is easy to identify and troubleshoot, because the Latin-1 encoding in particular is obvious and transparent (every byte is encoded exactly as itself).